# How do I execute a single line of OCaml code in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, ocaml

I'm using Emacs to edit an OCaml file, and I want to run one single line of code to make sure it type checks. What key command do I use to accomplish this? `C-c C-b` runs the entire file, but I just want one line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C-c C-e (as evaluate Expression), see the tuareg cheat sheets:

http://www.ocamlpro.com/files/tuareg-mode.pdf